# nHibernate SchemaUpdate Failing

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, schema, ddl

I'm trying to use the schema update feature in nHibernate against an Oracle 11g database and it's throwing the following exception: "More restrictions were provided than the requested schema ('Tables') supports."

It appears to be an ado.net exception, but I can't find much information for it.  Any insight towards this exception would be great. If it's helpful, I'm using the System.Data.OracleClient assembly to talk to Oracle.

Comment: Stacktrace? Sample code? Can you reproduce this with some simple configuration?

Comment: Please always post at least the stack trace, otherwise diagnosing issues becomes guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I was bumping into an error that has already been fixed according to [NH-1480](http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NH-1480).  We were using 2.1 Alpha 1 that was shipping alongside Fluent NHibernate.  Rebuilding Fluent NHibernate against 2.1 Beta 1 solved this issue.